# AngularJS, apos o select, salvar em uma outra tabela

Tags: angularjs

Criei um função chamada `buscarCep()` que me retorna o seguinte objeto:

> endereco_codigo: 453114, bairro_codigo: 15698, endereco_cep:
>   17052330,…

Tenho uma outra função que se chama `salvar`, onde salva esses dados junto com outros digitados no meu *BD*.
Como eu faço para mostrar nos meu capos que deveriam ser auto-preenchidos?

Exemplo:

```
< input name="endereco" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="cadastro.endereco.endereco" maxlength="60" >
```

Se digitar algo neste input, salva certinho no meu *BD*, mas eu queria que ao buscar completasse esse campo para eu salvar.

Comment: Quando ele busca do bd, você está setando os valores retornados nas variáveis utilizadas como ngModel?

Answer (score 2):

Você deve salvar o retorno no $scope e usar ng-model nos inputs.

Por exemplo:

```
$scope.resultado = obj; // obj que retornou sua função  buscarCep();


< input name="endereco" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="resultado.endereco_codigo" maxlength="60" >
```